How to switch user withing code execution PL/SQL
I encountered an issue where I do have to execute a package on archive_schema, which has to create a table on production_schema, grant it to some other users and some other stuff.
I would want the procedure to connect to the production_schema and create the table, or create some job that is on the production_schema that does the needed job.
However, we do not have "create any table" privilege and unfortunately it will not be granted.
It is within the same database, just different users.

You can have a procedure in production_schema that creates a table there (like this or this), and grant execute on that to archive_schema. But why are you creating tables at run-time at all?

Generally, you don't. This seems like an XY-problem where the problem is X but you think you need to solve it by doing Y (i.e. dynamically creating tables); Y is probably not the solution but you are only asking how to do Y and not how should I solve the underlying problem X.

If the execution is with different users, is it not logical to have different set of permissions for them?
Also as @MT0 mentioned, it is not advisable to switch production user that is intended to have certain permission with other user.

@MT0 and others, the goal was to have archive schema that needs to move data from production. However temporary tables were must for this purpose, due to partition exchanging (creating temp table, storing partition in it, exchanging it to archive). Other ways were possible but this was the fastest.
The issue was resolved via creating procedure on production_scheme that creates jobs, having pl/sql statement as parameter and being granted to archive scheme. Not ideal solution, but only one found. Thx
